# passwd command in shell script

Tags: shell, passwords, stdin, opensolaris

I am making a shell script that automatically create users, but I cannot think of how to use passwd command within my shell script, how should I use it with shell script? --stdin option doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`expect(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/).

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations of `passwd` have the `--stdin` flag which you can use like so:

```
passwd --stdin user <<<"SoMePasSw0rd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Debian

```
echo -e "$NEWPASS\n$NEWPASS" | passwd $USER
```